# BinaryReader.ReadByte() doesn't TimedOut

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, stream, binaryreader, request-cancelling

I have an internet stream and I am creating reader from that

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
```

and after that I am reading bytes for searching "sync word"

```
if (reader.ReadByte() != magic[i++])
```

But sometimes i have a problem with `ReadByte()`. I expected that if reader cannot read bytes from the stream it will throw exception, but it not throwing anything. (Server is not shutdown, just don't provide bytes).

So my question is - how to time out this method? 
I can use TPL with CancellationToken, but don't understand how to cancel method ReadByte when it is needed.

Comment: How did you obtain the stream? You may well be able to set a timeout there.

Comment: I using TcpClient for getting stream client.GetStream();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that we now know this is from a `TcpClient`, I'd suggest setting the [`TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout.aspx) before requesting the stream. That should make the read call time out appropriately.

(On the other hand, I didn't think `TcpClient` was available on WP7, so I'm not sure how you're using it...)

Comment: I using SocketEx library for that. Thx, I will see to change to native way client-server communication via standard WP7 sockets.